# jquery ajax code is not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I wrote a code in jquery and ajax as an example for study.But it is not working.this is the code.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#ra").click(function(){  
        var value=145;
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: ({name: value}),
            success: function(data){
            $("#raaagh").html(data);
            }
        });        
    });
});
```

php

```
<?php
    $score = "1";    
    $userAnswer = $_POST['name'];    
    if ($_POST['name'] == "145"){
        $score++;
    }       
    echo $score;    
?>
```

html

```
<button id="ra">Ajax Away</button>
<div id="raaagh"></div>
```

Comment: its html part is<button id="ra">Ajax Away</button>
<div id="raaagh"></div>

Comment: *it is not working* is hard to analyse. Please elaborate your problem in more detail.

Comment: what exactly is not working? Does the ajax call work? Is the click fired?

Comment: click function is not calling

Comment: have you debugged it with an `alert('click');` ?

Comment: Its always a good idea to use a developer tool plugin for your browser when debugging ajax calls, something like fire bug or IE's developer tools, check out the network tab. You will be able to see whats happening.

Comment: If your click function is'nt working you either forgot to include jQuery, or you don't have an element with the ID `ra`. Also it should be just `data: {name: value},` without the parenthesis.

Comment: @user1885150: http://jsfiddle.net/SLyCS/ your *click handler* gets most certainly called. The problem is most likely located in your PHP, maybe it won't return the data proberly.

Comment: @user1885150 - have you included JQuery??

Comment: Console errors? does the php work in a form and what does it return?

Comment: @LeighCiechanowski - Seriously? `IE's developer tools` ? Like that will help !

Comment: `Please help me` we're trying, but it isn't easy. Do you get any output in `#raaagh`?

Comment: @adeneo You're right, but the lack of parentheses won't break it.

Comment: Hey.... :) IE's tools aren't half bad now a days, I have to target IE as the main browser we support, and now I just don't bother with firebug anymore, IE has caught up here.

Comment: you trying to increment `$score` - it is string

Comment: @IvanSolntsev - you are right. He need to change in `php` code. change `$score="1"` to `$score=1`

Comment: @IvanSolntsev - PHP does'nt care, it converts it automagically.

Comment: I have a doubt,how to pass more than one parameter in data:

Comment: `data: {first: value, second: value, third: value}`

Comment: And the error was what exactly, forgetting to include jQuery ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code.. I think you missed including `JQuery`:

html.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#ra").click(function(){  
        var value=145;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: ({name: value}), //you can POST multiple parameters
            //data: ({name: value, email:value, phone: value}),
            success: function(data){
                $("#raaagh").html(data);
            }
        });        
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="ra">Ajax Away</button>
    <div id="raaagh"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
    $score = 1;
    $userAnswer = $_POST['name'];    
    if ($_POST['name'] == "145"){
        $score++;
    }       
    echo $score;    
?>
```

Comment: how to pass more than one parameter in data:

Comment: @user1885150 - check it out. i have edited my answer for passing multiple parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

echo json_encode($score);

Comment: json_encode is a great function, but not for one single number ?

Comment: how to pass more than one argument in data?